# rust lang check port and connection

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to rust lang, I want to write the test case to below is code to check the port and connection is working.

```
use tonic::{transport::Server}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:50051".parse()?;

    Server::builder()
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: And? What's the question here? Does this code not compile? compile but crash? run but not do what you want? Either way you will need to give us the error message if any and a description of the actual vs expected behaviours.

Comment: spawn a new thread and start the server from there. Then from another thread open a connection to the server

Comment: My question here is can we create mock for tonic server for testing